# How many unlock operation are required to unlock an object that is locked several times in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

Reading java language specification - memory model I cam across this statement .

> A thread t may lock a particular monitor multiple times; each unlock
>   reverses the effect of one lock operation.

Then I went to try this by using the code below, however it doesn't seem to work. 
Either I don't understand the statement or my code is not doing what I want it to ...

```
public class MultipleLocks {


private static final Object LOCK = new Object();

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            synchronized (LOCK) {
                //some code ...
            }
        }


        synchronized (LOCK) {
            try {
                LOCK.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    t1.start();

    Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {

        synchronized (LOCK) {
            System.out.println("I can acquire a lock !");
        }
    });

    t2.start();

    synchronized (LOCK) {
        LOCK.notify();
    }

    }


}
```

***11 - Locks 
Unlock only ONCE ?***

The code show that only one lock operation is required, or I am missing something ?

***EDIT:***

If my code is wrong, how can I simulate acquiring a lock n-times and release it n-time, and if n-1 times is released then the the thread should keep locking the lock ?

Comment: You're missing that the thread only acquires one lock at a time. `multipleLock` will leave the `LOCK` object unlocked since the `synchronized` block acquiring the lock is left.

Comment: [Specification that is quoted on the OP question](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html)

Comment: You need one lock operation to aquire the lock on an object (given that nothing else got it locked). Then, the same object can lock it again, as often as it wants to. But you need to unlock it, to set it free. The amount of unlocks must be the exact same amout of locks, that have been performed

Comment: @Korashen Not really, I am locking it 10-times but unlocking it once

Comment: Every time you exit a `synchronized` block, the lock is unlocked.

Comment: @Adelin You actually do not do that, as the synchronized block aquires a Lock on enter but releases it on exit. And then the next itteration starts. So you basically aquire and release one lock and you do that 10 times in sequence.

Comment: Re, "I am locking it 10-times but unlocking it once" Can you explain? Where are you "locking" it? Where are you "unlocking" it? A thread can't leave a `synchronized` block without unlocking the object.

Comment: Re, "A thread t may lock a particular monitor multiple times; each unlock reverses the effect of one lock operation." In other words, a thread `t` owns the monitor for some object until it has exited from _all_ blocks that are `synchronized` on that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question "*The code show that only one lock operation is required, or I am missing something ?*" has been answered by @Pete Kirkham.

The answer to the main question "*How many unlock operation are required to unlock an object that is locked several times in Java?*" is the one you quoted.

The following code shows how `Thread t1` "*lock a particular monitor multiple times*" and that "*each unlock reverses the effect of one lock operation*".

`Thread t1` enters the `synchronize` block three times. Evertime a `synchronize` block is entered an (additional) lock is aquired. Everytime a `synchronize` block is left a lock was released. Therefore first after `t1` left all`synchronize` blocks`Thread t2` can enter the `synchronize` block.

```
public class Locking {

    private static Object o = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Thread t1 = new Thread(Locking::lockSeveralTimes);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(Locking::lockOnce);
        t1.start();
        Thread.sleep(100); // give t1 some time to start
        t2.start();
    }

    protected static void lockOnce() {
        synchronized (o) {
            System.out.println("DONE");
        }
    }

    protected static void lockSeveralTimes() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Has Lock: " + Thread.holdsLock(o));
            synchronized (o) {
                System.out.println("Aquired Lock: " + Thread.holdsLock(o) + " / Times: " + getLockedMonitorsCount());
                waitOneSecond();
                synchronized (o) {
                    System.out.println("Aquired Lock: " + Thread.holdsLock(o) + " / Times: " + getLockedMonitorsCount());
                    waitOneSecond();
                    synchronized (o) {
                        System.out.println("Aquired Lock: " + Thread.holdsLock(o) + " / Times: " + getLockedMonitorsCount());
                        waitOneSecond();
                        System.out.println("Going to release lock. Still holds: " + Thread.holdsLock(o) + " / Times: " + getLockedMonitorsCount());
                    }
                    waitOneSecond();
                    System.out.println("Going to release lock. Still holds: " + Thread.holdsLock(o) + " / Times: " + getLockedMonitorsCount());
                }
                waitOneSecond();
                System.out.println("Going to release lock. Still holds: " + Thread.holdsLock(o) + " / Times: " + getLockedMonitorsCount());
            }
            System.out.println("Still holds: " + Thread.holdsLock(o));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected static void waitOneSecond() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    protected static int getLockedMonitorsCount() {
        return ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getThreadInfo(new long[] { Thread.currentThread().getId() }, true, false)[0].getLockedMonitors().length;
    }

}
```

The output is:

```
Has Lock: false
Aquired Lock: true / Times: 1
Aquired Lock: true / Times: 2
Aquired Lock: true / Times: 3
Going to release lock. Still holds: true / Times: 3
Going to release lock. Still holds: true / Times: 2
Going to release lock. Still holds: true / Times: 1
Still holds: false
DONE
```

---

Runs for me with JDK 8.

Comment: I see, this is what I was locking for, so it is a synchronize inside another ... I see :)

Comment: Yes ... and if you want to do it even shorter,, you can define a mthod with a `synchronize` block and call the method within recursive ... to a certain point, e.g. it holds 100 locks.

Answer (score 2):

This code isn't doing anything to the state of the object:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        synchronized (LOCK) { // lock gained on LOCK object
            //some code ...
        } // lock released on LOCK object
    }
```

The lock is gained at the start of the synchronized block and released at the end. Doing this ten times leaves the object in the same state as it was in at the start of the loop.

Thread1 then acquires the lock then waits, which causes it to release the lock until another thread notifies the object.

> The thread releases ownership of this monitor and waits until another
>   thread notifies threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up
>   [Object.wait() javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait())

Thread2 acquires a lock, prints the only output of the program, then releases the lock.

The main thread acquires a lock, notifies one waiting thread, then releases the lock.

So there are several orderings in which the threads can acquire the lock, all of which result in the same output.